# How to re-build methods to return list of clients?

Tags: java, arraylist, mockito

I need to re-build some of my methods to return the list of clients. I need that, because in that moment I can't write any unit tests.
Here is my method that is responsible for adding clients to DataBase. As you can see values like: name, surname... are fetched from already made client object.
**CarRentalSQLDatabase**

```
@Override
public void addClient(Client client) throws SQLException {
    preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement("insert into client" + "(namee, surname, street,houseNumber,city,peselNumber,rentDate, clientNumber)" + "values(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");

    preparedStatement.setString(1, client.getName());
    preparedStatement.setString(2, client.getSurname());
    preparedStatement.setString(3, client.getStreet());
    preparedStatement.setInt(4, client.getHouseNumber());
    preparedStatement.setString(5, client.getCity());
    preparedStatement.setLong(6, client.getPeselNumber());
    preparedStatement.setString(7, client.getRentDate());
    preparedStatement.setInt(8, client.getClientNumber());

    preparedStatement.executeUpdate();
}
```

Here is my method that is reponsible for displaying all clients on the screen:
**CarRentalSQLDatabase**

```
@Override
public void populateTableViewClients() throws SQLException {
    String sql = "SELECT * FROM `client`";
    result = statement.executeQuery(sql);

    while (result.next()) {

        String namee = result.getString("namee");
        String surname = result.getString("surname");
        String street = result.getString("street");
        int houseNumber = result.getInt("houseNumber");
        long peselNumber = result.getLong("peselNumber");
        String rentDate = result.getString("rentDate");
        System.out.println("----------------------------");
        System.out.printf("Name:" + namee + "\nSurname:" + surname + "\nStreet:" + street + "\nNumber of house:" + houseNumber + "\nPesel number:" + peselNumber + "\nDate of rental:" + rentDate + "\n");
        System.out.println("----------------------------");
    }
}
```

I wanted to build something like this:

```
public List<Client> getAllCustomers() throws SQLException {
    List<Client> listOfClients = new ArrayList<Client>();

    String sql = "SELECT * FROM `client`";
    result = statement.executeQuery(sql);
    //....
    return listOfClients;
}
```

**So how to retrieve data from my DataBase and put it in ArrayList?**
All that is needed to do test like:

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
class CarRentalOptionsTest{
CarRentalOptions objUnderTests;

@Test
public void addedCustomerShouldBeSaved(){

    CarRentalStorage storageMock = mock(CarRentalStorage.class);

    objUnderTests = new CarRentalOptions(storageMock);

    Client client = new Client();
    objUnderTests.addClient(client);

    verify(storageMock).addCustomer(client);


    List<Customer> customers = new ArrayList<>();
    customers.add(client);
    when(storageMock.getAllCustomers()).thenReturn(customers);

    Assert.assertTrue(objUnderTests.isCustomerRegistered(customer));
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public List<Client> getAllCustomers() throws SQLException {
    List<Client> listOfClients = new ArrayList<Client>();

    String sql = "SELECT * FROM `client`";
    result = statement.executeQuery(sql);

    while (result.next()) {
        Client client = new Client();
        client.setName(result.getString("namee"));
        client.setSurname(result.getString("surname"));
        // ... and so on
        listOfClients.add(client);
    }

    return listOfClients;
}
```